# how do i vertical align these 2boxs inside this red box?

Tags: html, css

How do i vertical align the white box and green box inside red box. I want it look like in the picture below. Thanks you. guys are the best. here is http://jsfiddle.net/hamdlink/JxDn5/
[image]

```
<style>
    *{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    .box{
        width:600px;
        height:600px;
        position: absolute;
        margin:auto;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        top:0;
        background: red;
    }

    .box2{
        margin:0 auto;
        background: green;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }

    .box3{
        margin:0 auto;
        background: white;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }
    .whole-background{
        position: absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }
</style>
    <div class="whole-background"></div>

    <div class="box">
        <div class="box2"></div>
        <div class="box3"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: .box2 { margin-top: 200px; } :) jocking

Answer (score 1):

The red box should be used as a **table-cell**.
The 2 little boxes should be displayed in **inline-block**;

Horizontal alignment: text-align: center;
Vertical alignment: vertical-align: middle;

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/JxDn5/2/

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.box{
    width:100px;
    height:600px;
    margin:auto;
    background: red;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
padding: 0 250px;
}

.box2{
    margin:0 auto;
    background: green;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.box3{
    margin:0 auto;
    background: white;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.whole-background{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

Comment: There are still some very important styles for the `.box` which you don't mention (while they are present in the code). The `.box` has the width being equal to the inner boxes' (`100px`) (to put 2 inner boxes to separate lines) and set the `padding: 0 250px` to make the total width of the `.box` being equal to `600px`. I like this solution :) +1

Comment: @jgthms, but i still want the red box to vertical align middle and horizontal align center to the window(browser).

Comment: @sopanha you can add this style `body { display:table; margin:auto; }` because the `body` is the container of your `box`. If it has another container, just replace `body` with that one.

Comment: @KingKing add style body won't make the red box vertical align middle to the browser.

Comment: @sopanha looks like you have to use the final solution with absolute positioning (for the `box`), try this on webkit-based browsers http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/JxDn5/3/